# What is the relationship between SageMaker's pipeline and domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pipeline, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I created a new domain in the console, then entered Studio and saw pipelines from another domain in the pipeline section. However, after creating my own pipeline, I couldn't see it in other domains.

My question is whether there are parameters or settings when creating a pipeline that determine whether it's visible to other domains or not.

Thanks

The docs and workshops seem only to properly describe the Python SDK usage,it would be really helpful if someone could clear this up for me

Answer (score 0):

see the documentation here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/domain-multiple.html#domain-multiple-filtering

In short, all domain resources (like jobs, pipelines etc) are tagged with the domain ARN where it was created, and the UI only shows resources that are tagged with the right domain ARN.

If you are seeing resources created in a different domain, high chances that the resource was created prior to automatic tagging. Resources without any tags will be displayed across domains.